# How to reload data in UITableView when popping view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, viewcontroller

If I have two `ViewControllers` one which contains a `UITableView` and another which updates data in the `tableView`. How would I reload the table data once I pop of the `viewController` and go back to the view with the `tableView`?

I already tried using `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Use Custom delegate to closure to pass data from second view controller to first view controller. Update the data source and reload the tableview in `viewWillAppear` of first view controller

Comment: Just did that does not seem to make a difference I added in a print statement so it does enter viewWillAppear but the table does not update for some reason

Comment: Show how do you pass data between the view controllers?

Answer (score 2):

You could use viewWillAppear just like Rajesh suggested:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Or you could use a callback function to pass data and reload view controller 1's tableview.

In ViewController 2, define your callback function:

```
// Callback function
var callbackResult: ((data) -> ())?
```

And call it before going back to ViewController 1:

```
    callbackResult?(data)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

In ViewController 1, use the callback function's closure to collect the result and reload your tableView. This can happen inside prepareForSegue, for example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToViewController2" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        // Set any variable in ViewController2
        destinationVC.callbackResult = { result in
        // assign passing data etc..
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That worked thank you can not upvote because rep but I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Log when using viewWillAppear: *"[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes."*

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing something like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    func showUpdatingViewController() {
        let vc = UpdatingViewController()

        vc.onUpdate = { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}

class UpdatingViewController: UIViewController {

    var onUpdate: (() -> Void)?

    func updatesFinished() {
        onUpdate?()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue and using `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` did not help me to reload the tableview.

I solved my situation by putting the `reloadData()` call within the `unwindSegue`

```
  @IBAction func unwindToVCSetupDataScreen(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    /// Nothing is actually needed here
    /// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaSlHXNah7E @6:25
    /// CTRL-Drag from Back button to the "exit" square at the very top of VC
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```